# How could I remove duplicated data without id

Tags: mongodb

I need to import lot of data into mongoDB.

But many data may be duplicated, how to remove duplicated data in mongoDB with a elegant way.

It's ugly and inefficient to do check `Collection.find({ALL_THE_FIELDS}).exist?` before importing new record.

To do `index` is also inefficient because you need to do indexing for hundreds fields.

I want to import all data and remove duplicated records in collection later.

How to do it ? Thanks

The following is one document sample,

I need to import millions of the sort of documents, and there will be many duplicated documents. So I need to find out a way to remove duplicated documents

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5550649669702d1901070000"),
  "report_type": "com_disagg",
  "item": "WHEAT",
  "exchange": "CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",
  "product_exchange": "WHEAT - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",
  "date": new Date("2009-12-08T08:00:00+0800"),
  "timestamp_utc": NumberLong(1260230400000),
  "updated_at": new Date(1431331990505),
  "created_at": new Date(1431331990498),
  "symbol_code_id": ObjectId("5550645169702d1864020000"),
  "symbol": "W",
  "CFTC_Contract_Market_Code": "001602",
  "CFTC_Market_Code": "CBT",
  "CFTC_Region_Code": "00",
  "CFTC_Commodity_Code": "001",
  "Open_Interest_All": "421790.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Long_ALL": "34399.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Short_ALL": "176446.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Long_All": "167220.0",
  "Swap__Positions_Short_All": "18118.0",
  "Swap__Positions_Spread_All": "11837.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Long_ALL": "61511.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Short_ALL": "42756.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Spread_ALL": "34393.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Long_ALL": "14072.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Short_ALL": "21546.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Spread_ALL": "65296.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Long_All": "388728.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Short_All": "370392.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Long_All": "33062.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Short_All": "51398.0",
  "Open_Interest_Old": "281017.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Long_Old": "16525.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Short_Old": "122260.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Long_Old": "117778.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Short_Old": "5864.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Spread_Old": "4270.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Long_Old": "54489.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Short_Old": "44462.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Spread_Old": "10319.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Long_Old": "9407.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Short_Old": "15516.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Spread_Old": "47020.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Long_Old": "259809.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Short_Old": "249712.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Long_Old": "21208.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Short_Old": "31304.0",
  "Open_Interest_Other": "140773.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Long_Other": "17875.0",
  "Prod_Merc_Positions_Short_Other": "54186.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Long_Other": "51313.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Short_Other": "14125.0",
  "Swap_Positions_Spread_Other": "5696.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Long_Other": "21387.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Short_Other": "12659.0",
  "M_Money_Positions_Spread_Other": "9708.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Long_Other": "7275.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Short_Other": "8640.0",
  "Other_Rept_Positions_Spread_Othr": "15665.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Long_Other": "128919.0",
  "Tot_Rept_Positions_Short_Other": "120679.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Long_Other": "11855.0",
  "NonRept_Positions_Short_Other": "20094.0",
  "Change_in_Open_Interest_All": "88.0",
  "Change_in_Prod_Merc_Long_All": "-287.0",
  "Change_in_Prod_Merc_Short_All": "-4032.0",
  "Change_in_Swap_Long_All": "-768.0",
  "Change_in_Swap_Short_All": "1679.0",
  "Change_in_Swap_Spread_All": "268.0",
  "Change_in_M_Money_Long_All": "-1992.0",
  "Change_in_M_Money_Short_All": "2243.0",
  "Change_in_M_Money_Spread_All": "45.0",
  "Change_in_Other_Rept_Long_All": "1475.0",
  "Change_in_Other_Rept_Short_All": "-4019.0",
  "Change_in_Other_Rept_Spread_All": "1368.0",
  "Change_in_Tot_Rept_Long_All": "110.0",
  "Change_in_Tot_Rept_Short_All": "-2449.0",
  "Change_in_NonRept_Long_All": "-22.0",
  "Change_in_NonRept_Short_All": "2537.0",
  "Pct_of_Open_Interest_All": "100.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Long_All": "8.2",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Short_All": "41.8",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Long_All": "39.6",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Short_All": "4.3",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Spread_All": "2.8",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Long_All": "14.6",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Short_All": "10.1",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Spread_All": "8.2",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Long_All": "3.3",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Short_All": "5.1",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Spread_All": "15.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Long_All": "92.2",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Short_All": "87.8",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Long_All": "7.8",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Short_All": "12.2",
  "Pct_of_Open_Interest_Old": "100.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Long_Old": "5.9",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Short_Old": "43.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Long_Old": "41.9",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Short_Old": "2.1",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Spread_Old": "1.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Long_Old": "19.4",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Short_Old": "15.8",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Spread_Old": "3.7",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Long_Old": "3.3",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Short_Old": "5.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Spread_Old": "16.7",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Long_Old": "92.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Short_Old": "88.9",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Long_Old": "7.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Short_Old": "11.1",
  "Pct_of_Open_Interest_Other": "100.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Long_Other": "12.7",
  "Pct_of_OI_Prod_Merc_Short_Other": "38.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Long_Other": "36.5",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Short_Other": "10.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_Swap_Spread_Other": "4.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Long_Other": "15.2",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Short_Other": "9.0",
  "Pct_of_OI_M_Money_Spread_Other": "6.9",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Long_Other": "5.2",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Short_Other": "6.1",
  "Pct_of_OI_Other_Rept_Spread_Othr": "11.1",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Long_Other": "91.6",
  "Pct_of_OI_Tot_Rept_Short_Other": "85.7",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Long_Other": "8.4",
  "Pct_of_OI_NonRept_Short_Other": "14.3",
  "Traders_Tot_All": "359.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Long_All": "48.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Short_All": "76.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Long_All": "18.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Short_All": "9.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Spread_All": "21.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Long_All": "62.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Short_All": "60.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Spread_All": "45.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Long_All": "59.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Short_All": "61.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Spread_All": "74.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Long_All": "263.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Short_All": "276.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Old": "337.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Long_Old": "40.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Short_Old": "72.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Long_Old": "19.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Short_Old": "8.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Spread_Old": "13.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Long_Old": "59.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Short_Old": "56.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Spread_Old": "34.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Long_Old": "50.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Short_Old": "65.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Spread_Old": "61.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Long_Old": "224.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Short_Old": "253.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Other": "206.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Long_Other": "25.0",
  "Traders_Prod_Merc_Short_Other": "62.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Long_Other": "11.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Short_Other": "11.0",
  "Traders_Swap_Spread_Other": "17.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Long_Other": "18.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Short_Other": "22.0",
  "Traders_M_Money_Spread_Other": "16.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Long_Other": "37.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Short_Other": "37.0",
  "Traders_Other_Rept_Spread_Other": "46.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Long_Other": "133.0",
  "Traders_Tot_Rept_Short_Other": "171.0",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Long_All": "21.3",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Short_All": "21.3",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Long_All": "35.4",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Short_All": "30.0",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Long_All": "20.5",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Short_All": "18.1",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Long_All": "34.2",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Short_All": "24.6",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Long_Old": "27.3",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Short_Old": "22.1",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Long_Old": "39.6",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Short_Old": "31.4",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Long_Old": "27.2",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Short_Old": "20.0",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Long_Old": "38.9",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Short_Old": "27.9",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Long_Other": "37.4",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_4_TDR_Short_Other": "27.6",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Long_Other": "49.2",
  "Conc_Gross_LE_8_TDR_Short_Other": "37.0",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Long_Other": "35.5",
  "Conc_Net_LE_4_TDR_Short_Other": "22.8",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Long_Other": "42.6",
  "Conc_Net_LE_8_TDR_Short_Other": "29.0",
  "Contract_Units": "(CONTRACTS OF 5,000 BUSHELS)",
  "CFTC_SubGroup_Code": "A10",
  "FutOnly_or_Combined": "Combined"
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) I don't see what data are duplicate, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: what if you calculate hash for every imported record based on set of fields and save it as new additional field. Before saving new record you have to calculate hash and check if this hash already exists in the DB.

Comment: @marijnz0r The following is one document sample,

I need to import millions of the sort of documents, and there will be many duplicated documents. So I need to find out a way to remove duplicated documents

Comment: @victork will this method too slow for millions data in one day ?

Comment: @user3675188 Do you mean the document is identical, or do they include  small differences like the timestamp? Becaus if that's the case, there's no problem. MongoDB is designed to handle documents like this.

Comment: @user3675188 unfortunatly I have not such exprience, and I cannot say for sure. May be if you create index based on just one hash field instead of all fields, importing process will not take too much time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete duplicates in MongoDb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337123/how-can-i-delete-duplicates-in-mongodb)